# Format string - spaces between every three digit

Tags: python

How to simple format string with decimal number for show it with spaces between every three digits?

I can make something like this:

```
some_result = '12345678,46'
' '.join(re.findall('...?', test[:test.find(',')]))+test[test.find(','):]
```

and result is:

```
'123 456 78,46'
```

but I want:

```
'12 345 678,46'
```

Comment: What about `'12345678,46123'`?

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Usually, people don't put thousands separators after the decimal point. At least PEP 378 formatting doesn't, and neither does any LC_NUMERIC I can dig up.

Comment: Try to make spaces from the `end` not from the beginning

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a bit hacky, but:

```
format(12345678.46, ',').replace(',', ' ').replace('.', ',')
```

As described in [Format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language), in a format_spec:

> The ',' option signals the use of a comma for a thousands separator.

Then we just replace each comma with a space, then the decimal point with a comma, and we're done.

For more complex cases using `str.format` instead of `format`, the format_spec goes after the colon, as in:

```
'{:,}'.format(12345678.46)
```

See [PEP 378](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0378/) for details.

---

Meanwhile, if you're just trying to use the standard grouping and separators for your system's locale, there are easier ways to do that—the `n` format type, or the `locale.format` function, etc. For example:

```
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'pl_PL')
>>> format(12345678, 'n')
12 345 678
>>> locale.format('%.2f' 12345678.12, grouping=True)
12 345 678,46
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC, 'fr_FR')
>>> locale.format('%.2f' 12345678.12, grouping=True)
12345678,46
>>> locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_AU')
>>> locale.format('%.2f' 12345678.12, grouping=True)
12,345,678.46
```

If your system locale is, say, `pl_PL`, just calling `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_NUMERIC)` (or `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL)`) will pick up the Polish settings that you want, but the same person running your program in Australia will pick up the Australian settings that he wants.

Answer (score 5):

I think a regex would be much nicer:

```
>>> import re
>>> some_result = '12345678,46'
>>> re.sub(r"\B(?=(?:\d{3})+,)", " ", some_result)
'12 345 678,46'
```

**Explanation:**

```
\B       # Assert that we're not at the start of a number
(?=      # Assert that the following regex could match from here:
 (?:     # The following non-capturing group
  \d{3}  # which contains three digits
 )+      # and can be matched one or more times
 ,       # until a comma follows.
)        # End of lookahead assertion
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
' '.join(re.findall('...?',test[:test.find(',')][::-1]))[::-1]+test[test.find(','):]
```

You have used regex which starts matching a string from the **start**. But you want to group the 3 numbers from the **end** (before comma).

So reverse the string before comma, apply the same logic and then reverse it back.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the string format for the 12 345 678,46
print("{:,}".format(t1).replace(',',' '))

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).